# Looking for a closed-form expression

Tags: real-analysis

I asked a question earlier, but it was too complicated. Sorry for the confusion. I simplified my proof, now I only need the following sequence, but again, I can't find an expression. The sequence I have is:

$$a_n=\overbrace{\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}}^{\text{2 times}},\overbrace{\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4}}^{\text{2 times}},\overbrace{\frac{1}{8},\frac{1}{8},\frac{1}{8},\frac{1}{8}}^{\text{4 times}},\overbrace{\frac{1}{16},\ldots\frac{1}{16}}^{\text{8 times}},\overbrace{\frac{1}{32},\ldots\frac{1}{32}}^{\text{16 times}},\ldots$$

and the problem I'm trying to solve requires me to show that for $k_n=\frac{1}{2n}$ for every n it holds that $a_n \leq 2 \cdot k_n$, which is quite obvious if you write the sequences below each other. Thanks for any help!

\begin{align} n=1;& \quad 1/2 \leq 2 \cdot 1/2 = 1 \cr n=2;& \quad 1/2 \leq 2 \cdot 1/4 = 1/2 \cr n=3;& \quad 1/4 \leq 2 \cdot 1/6 = 1/3 \cr n=4;& \quad 1/4 \leq 2 \cdot 1/8 = 1/4 \cr n=5;& \quad 1/8 \leq 2 \cdot 1/10 = 1/5\end{align}

you can continue this, and you will notice that the change in $a_n$ will always occur sharply when it is about to fail (at least as far as I tried).

Comment: Did you mean to write $\frac{1}{2}$ only once?

Comment: No, it's correct as I wrote it.

Comment: Well, what's the pattern?  Does every $\frac 1{2^k}$ appear $2^{k-1}$ times except for $\frac 12$ which appears twice?

Comment: Yes, that's the pattern. I just don't know how to use that to proof what I stated above. Do I need the closed-form expression or can I show it in a different way?

Comment: But....$a_4=\frac 14$ while $k_4=\frac 18$.

Comment: Just corrected that. I meant it the other way around.

Comment: But $a_1=k_1$.  Please take some time to think through what you want to ask and then to ask it clearly.  Show numerically that whatever claim it is you want to prove is true for, say, the first $5$ terms.

Comment: Okay yeah, I need to think of the ratio I want to express. One second.

Comment: Okay, I want to show that $a_n \leq 2 \cdot k_n$ for every n.

Comment: FYI, I fixed two typos in your $n=4$ and $n=5$ lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $n \geq 2$, you can write $$a_n = \frac{1}{2^{\lceil \log_2 n\rceil}}$$
where $\lceil \cdot \rceil$ denotes the ceiling function. Then, since
$$\lceil \log_2 n\rceil \geq \log_2 n$$
we have
$$2^{\lceil \log_2 n\rceil} \geq 2^{\log_2 n} = n$$
and therefore
$$a_n = \frac{1}{2^{\lceil \log_2 n\rceil}} \leq \frac{1}{n} = 2 \frac{1}{2n} = 2 k_n$$
For $n=1$ the above expression for $a_n$ doesn't hold, but the inequality is still true:
$$a_1 = \frac{1}{2} \leq 1 = 2k_1$$

Comment: Thank you this looks so smooth. The reason I want to study math :D. And are you sure for $n=1$ it's not true?

Comment: @MarcelBraasch For $n=1$ we have $a_n = 1/2$ and $2k_n = 2\frac{1}{2n} = 1/n = 1$.

Comment: Then it's true that 1/2 $\leq$ 1.

Comment: Under that circumstance, I don't need the restriction n $\geq$ 2, do I?

Comment: Ah yeah sorry, I was still thinking in terms of the original problem statement. Will fix.